# Change positions of objects on the stage by click - ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I have somme mc's on the stage an I want thatto change on mc with antoher by clicking on them. For example if I click on mc1 and than on mc2 than they schould change the positions.
any ideea how o do that?
thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a click event for the movieclip, and record it on a variable which movieclip was clicked, and then when the 2nd one is clicked, you just swap their positions. I'll give you a snippet of code that should work and should be enough to teach you how it's done.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
// Variable that will be used to store the 1st clicked MC
var lastClickedSwapMC;

//First we define the function to be called
function clickEventSwapMcs(evt : MouseEvent) {
    // Verify if a mc wasn't previously clicked
    if(lastClickedSwapMC == null) {
        // If it wasn't, it's the 1st time, so store the MC that was clicked
        lastClickedSwapMC = evt.currentTarget;
    } else {
        // If it was, we just need to swap the positions of the stored one with the one just clicked
        var savedX : Number = evt.currentTarget.x;
        var savedY : Number = evt.currentTarget.y;
        evt.currentTarget.x = lastClickedSwapMC.x;
        evt.currentTarget.y = lastClickedSwapMC.y;
        lastClickedSwapMC.x = savedX;
        lastClickedSwapMC.y = savedY;
        //After swaping their position, we clear the last clicked MC
        lastClickedSwapMC = null;
    }
}

//Now we register the click event on them so it calls the function
mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickEventSwapMcs);
mc2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickEventSwapMcs);
```

Comment: i have to mention something: this method is working only if use evt.target... and not "evt.currentTarget..."
so i am not aloud to use "current".
your solution is working but i get an error which says that "lastClickedSwapMC" is null after the first click. so i only use the position of the last clicked mc. "lastClickedSwapMC" will never get null.

Comment: Hello, I don't understand what's going on for you. I've tested it on a fla of my own and it works flawlessly. About the target and currentTarget difference, check this:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html
But basically, the difference is that the currentTarget is the object who registered the Event, and target for MouseEvent is the Object which was clicked (which could be a son of mc1 and mc2, and not actually them).

Comment: do you know how to apply a blur effect to these mc's?
i allready mada a "glowFilter" bit I don't know how to apply it to every mc so that when i click on one of the mc that mc should glow and so on.
thank you